# What is Java Regex to check "=2245" or "= 545" or "= 22", etc?

Tags: java, regex

Ok, I want to check if a String has `=` as first character & then followed by any number, if there is a space between `=` & number then that is also ok.

Ok, here is the example,

```
String s="=2245"; --> return true
String s="=   545"; --> return true
String s="= 22"; --> return true
String s="= m  545"; --> return false
String s="=m545"; --> return false
```

SO here is what I did

```
if(s.matches("=[0-9]+")){
   return true;
}
```

This will work if there is not space between `=` & number

So I changed to:

```
if(s.matches("=\\s[0-9]+")){
       return true;
}
```

Then it will work if there is 1 space between the `=` & number & won't work in other cases.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"=\\s*\\d+"
```

The `*` means "zero or more repetitions", so this will work if the spaces are there or not.  The `\d` is an alternative way to write `[0-9]`.

Comment: Since you're so intent on nit-picking my annswer... Your `\s*` also matches tabs, newlines, vertical tabs... Not at all what he wants to allow!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^=[ ]*[0-9]+$
```

[The demo](http://regex101.com/r/eK8nY6) shows you what matches and doesn't match.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `=` matches the literal `=`
- `[ ]*` matches optional spaces. You don't need the brackets but it's easier to read.
- `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**In Java:**

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^=[ ]*[0-9]+$");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

Comment: If you use `matches` instead of the more complex alternative, then there is no point in using `^` and `$`.  Also no point in enclosing a single character in square brackets.

Comment: The OP used `matches`.  You have made it far more complicated.  For no apparent reason.  Needing `^` and `$` is just a side effect of your efforts to make this too complicated.

Comment: @DavidWallace What you call a `more complex alternative` is a good way of doing it if you're reusing a regex.

Comment: FYI Tum, the accepted wisdom among people who use regex a lot is that if you can anchor your regex with `^` and `$`... do so. If it happens that one Java method allows you not to use them... still use them, because when you find yourself using regex in a different environment (even a text editor), it's the easiest thing to forget.

Comment: @DavidWallace `your efforts to make this too complicated` Yeah, I worked really hard on it... lol... Really this is good sound regex, I don't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s.matches("=\\s*\\d+")){
       return true;
}
```

You should be use * that means "zero or more".

Check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `=\s*\d+`

[image]

`\s*` indicates                     whitespace `(\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")` (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))